# Meaning of "The Fact"

Tags: meaning-in-context, comprehension

### How is "The Fact" in this text understood?

> Creating further diplomatic distance is **the fact** that Raisi will be the first Iranian President to already be subject to US sanctions before even entering office.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your question can be much improved by providing a link and explaining how you tried to find the answer yourself. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Here "the fact" is used in its plain English meaning: the fact. The thing that is true. In this case, the thing that is true is that Raisi will be the first Iranian President with that condition.

Answer (score 1):

You will find odd sentences like this one in newspapers. The full sentence would be:

> ***[What is]*** creating further diplomatic distance is *the fact that...*

The word order is reversed, probably in an attempt to give some emphasis and render the sentence more lively, and also because the relative clause modifying ***fact*** is so long. The normal order would be:

> ***The fact*** that Raisi will be the first Iranian President to already be subject to US sanctions before even entering office, ***is creating*** [or *is what is creating*] further diplomatic distance.

What ***the fact*** refers to is explained in the relative at large. So there is no ambiguity as to what it means.